# How to connect to local docker db to test Get async methods

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, docker-compose, xunit

> I want to setup a connection to the database so that i can test 2 methods in 2 repositories, i want to test getAllGamesasync() method which returns a list of all entities from the database, and the getGamesByNameasync() method which returns games by their names.

> I am running docker to run the db and has populated rows with dummy data, i want to connect to it and run the test, So the question is What connection string to configure so code can talk to the SQL Server instance running in docker.

> The methods work fine i have tested using a In-Memory DB to manually insert entities and test them against the methods using the below unit test. So the unit test for Get_GamesByName looks like this:

```
public async Task Get_GamesByName()
{
  var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<GamesDbContext>()
  .options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("GamesDbContext")));


using (var context = new GamesDbContext(option))
{
   GamesRepository gamesRepository = new GamesRepository (context);

var result = await gamesRepository.GetGamesByNameAsync("Witcher");

Assert.Equal(2, result.count);
```

Comment: I removed the <sql> tag since this isn't related to the SQL _language_. Perhaps you should add <sql-server> instead?

Comment: What's your question? What connection string to configure so your code can talk to the SQL Server instance running in docker?

Comment: yes that's right you have said it better @CodeCaster

Comment: What's the actual value of GamesDbContext in your configuration?

Comment: You haven't told us anything about the Docker container configuration so... who knows? You've tagged `docker-compose` so does that mean you have a `docker-compose.yml` file? [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74111939/edit) your question to include it (scrub the passwords, obviously). Have you customized the container image with a `Dockerfile`? [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74111939/edit) your question to include it (scrub the passwords, obviously). Can you successfully connect to the database using SSMS or command line tools? Construct a connection string using the same details.